# Mapping from discriminated union property to object type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a bunch of objects that all have a property to discriminate them. And I have them as a union type. Now I want to create a mapping from the discriminated property to the actual type. I can make it myself, but its duplicitous and error prone so I was wondering if there was some way of generating this programmatically with TypeScript. :)

```
type X = { type: "x", x: number }
type Y = { type: "y", y: number }

type Value = X | Y
type Type = Value["type"]

// Is it possible to generate this?
type TypeToValue = {
    x: X,
    y: Y,
}

// Its useful for stuff like this
function getRecord<T extends Type>(type: T, id: string): TypeToValue[T] {
    return null as any
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Narrowing a return type from a generic, discriminated union in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46312206/narrowing-a-return-type-from-a-generic-discriminated-union-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1):

If the signature is always the same as in your post, whereas the value of `type` must match the associating property (e.g. `x` | `y`), you can get away with the following type:

```
type TypeToValue<T extends Type> = { [P in T]: number } & { type: T }
```

Which can be used as followed:

```
declare function getRecord<T extends Type>(type: T, id: string): TypeToValue<T>

const { type, x } = getRecord('x', 'aa');
```

There is no way to get the corresponding type from the union type that matches the `type` argument. [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20X%20%3D%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22x%22%2C%20x%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20Y%20%3D%20%7B%20type%3A%20%22y%22%2C%20y%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Value%20%3D%20X%20%7C%20Y%0D%0Atype%20Type%20%3D%20Value%5B%22type%22%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Is%20it%20possible%20to%20generate%20this%3F%0D%0Atype%20TypeToValue%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%20X%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20y%3A%20Y%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20--%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20TypeToValue2%3CT%20extends%20Type%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20T%5D%3A%20number%20%7D%20%26%20%7B%20type%3A%20T%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20getRecord%3CT%20extends%20Type%3E(type%3A%20T%2C%20id%3A%20string)%3A%20TypeToValue2%3CT%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20%7B%20type%2C%20x%20%7D%20%3D%20getRecord('x'%2C%20'aa')%3B)