# Narrowing an interface's generic union property as though it was a local variable in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an object of data I need to pass to one of two places based on which union member the object currently contains. Both places need all of the data in the object so recreating the object with the narrowed type seems a little silly. Obviously it works though.

As an alternative, I tried making the object's interface generic over the union so the interface can represent the object in all three places, thinking the automatic type narrowing might apply to the type parameter of `TestData`.

```js
interface UserData {
    kind: 'user',
    user: string,
}

interface ServerData {
    kind: 'server',
    url: string,
}

type DataTypes = UserData | ServerData

interface TestData<D extends DataTypes> {
    data: D,
    id: string,
}
```

Now the top class can use `TestData<DataTypes>` and the children can use `TestData<UserData>` or `TestData<ServerData>`. This works fine until you try and pass the object down to one of the children. The compiler will correctly narrow `TestData`'s `data` property, but this doesn't narrow the type of the actual object, which still has a type of `TestData<DataTypes>`. Here's an example.

```js
function basicNarrow(test: TestData<DataTypes>) {
    if (test.data.kind === 'user') {
        // Correctly narrowed to `UserData`
        test.data.user 
        // Error: Generic type not narrowed, still `TestData<DataTypes>
        const typed: TestData<UserData> = test 
    } else {
        // Correctly narrowed to `ServerData`
        test.data.url 
        // Error: Generic type not narrowed, still `TestData<DataTypes>
        const typed: TestData<ServerData> = test 
    }
}
```

At this point I could either use a type assertion or (again) create a new object to pass down the correct type, but after some digging I found [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50499316/11223651) which gives me

```js
type NarrowKind<T, N> = T extends { kind: N } ? T : never;

function predicateNarrow(test: TestData<DataTypes>) {
    const predicate = <K extends DataTypes['kind']>(narrow: TestData<DataTypes>, kind: K): narrow is TestData<NarrowKind<DataTypes, K>> => (
        narrow.data.kind === kind
    )

    if (predicate(test, 'user')) {
        // Correctly narrowed to `UserData`
        test.data.user 
        // Success! Generic type narrowed to `TestData<UserData>
        const typed: TestData<UserData> = test 
    } else {
        // Error: Not narrowed
        test.data.url 
        // Error: Generic type not narrowed, still `TestData<DataTypes>
        const typed: TestData<ServerData> = test 
    }
}
```

This does what I was after inside the `if` block, but the compiler won't narrow to the alternate case in the `else` block without another explicit check the way it would if `data` was just a local variable.

Here's an example of what I'd like the narrowed types to end up being ideally

```js
function idealNarrow(test: TestData<DataTypes>) {
    function isKind(/*???*/) { /*???*/ }

    if (isKind(test, 'user')) {
        const user: UserData = test.data 
        const typed: TestData<UserData> = test 
    } else {
        const server: ServerData = test.data 
        const typed: TestData<ServerData> = test 
    }
}
```

Either of the solutions could be used without issue, but `predicateNarrow(...)` is *so* close to what I was looking for, is there a way to combine these two behaviors somehow to narrow the whole generic `TestData<D>` type automatically in the else block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `TestData` itself is no [discriminated union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions), only `D` of contained `data` property is. In other words, TS can narrow `data` by `kind` discriminant, not the outer `TestData` type.

`predicate` can only check `TestData` to contain a specific type `UserData` or `ServerData`, but it cannot infer the other possible unions parts with the control flow in an `if/else` block. Possible solutions:

1) Narrow `DataTypes` and recombine `TestData` ([code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=26&ssc=2&pln=18&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdoBE5jsgbwChlTkBrUAEwC5kByAV0ynoBoSzno70wpQAcw4BfIkVCRYiFAGVoAN2y58xMhWp16LJaw7rGUADa9%20Q0eLABPAA4oceACq2I6ZAF40LB-gA%20yeShdH3FJaHgkZEdXMB8AHixkCAAPSBAqNx9nO3QAPkJOUioVOix9MmBaZD4BEGEiMSIYRhAEMGAAexBkACM4dGAEADk4KCgOgHcACgJkSrZkYrxkETpovnislzyASgL1YBhkKaW4ADpKdI93TyYWej21dTJT5AB6N69lPELnhC6%20MhrHYqutYio4hhvnB8p5ZvNFioVr8REkjJh9s8ikiPgFFNDfup-iBAcCIKCYvFAsEVLDCHMqAtXmJ1GIREA))

```
function basicNarrow({ id, data }: TestData<DataTypes>) {
    if (data.kind === 'user') {
        data // UserData
        const typed: TestData<UserData> = { id, data }
    } else {
        data // ServerData
        const typed: TestData<ServerData> = { id, data }
    }
}
```

2) Make `TestData` itself a discriminated union ([code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=22&ssc=2&pln=11&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdoBE5jsgbwChlTkBrUAEwC5kByAV0ynoBoSzno70wpQAcw4BfIkVCRYiFAGVoAN2y58xMhWp16LJaw7rGUADa9+Q0eLABPAA4oceACq2I6ZAF40LB-gA+yeShdHyJrO2RHVzAfAB4sZAgAD0gQKjcfZzt0AD4PZHiAMkJkYFpkPgEQQWQxIhhGEAQwYAB7EGQAIzh0YAQAOTgoKBaAdwAKSD46SL5YjJccgEpCTlJgGGQJqIA6SlSPd08mFnpltXUySbBkAHobr2U8ZCKCErKKoQBuGtWLhDa+MgwhAyjNoioYhhHnBcp4rr8RAkjJgVhdLlFbvdAsEVM9iqVTJVBN8xGjSP8QIDgaCorFsdDYUCogiiCIgA))

```
type DataTypes = UserData | ServerData
type TestData<D extends DataTypes> = D & { id: string }

function basicNarrow(test: TestData<DataTypes>) {
    if (test.kind === 'user') {
        test // UserData & { id: string; }
        const typed: TestData<UserData> = test
    } else {
        test // ServerData & { id: string; }
        const typed: TestData<ServerData> = test
    }
}
```