# Mypy type narrowing from return values

Tags: python, mypy, strong-typing, static-typing

I'm looking at the following typed Python example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Optional

class Thing:

    def does_intersect(self, other: Thing) -> bool:
        return True

    def intersect(self, other: Thing) -> Optional[Thing]:
        if self.does_intersect(other):
            return self
        else:
            return None

def my_function() -> Thing:
    thing = Thing()
    other_thing = Thing()
    if not thing.does_intersect(other_thing):
        return thing
    return thing.intersect(other_thing)
```

And the mypy documentation states:

> Mypy understands the implications return or exception raising can have for what type an object could be.

However, running mypy on this example returns:
`error: Incompatible return value type (got "Optional[Thing]", expected "Thing") Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)`

I understand that mypy can use TypeGuards, but they don't really seem to naturally solve this problem: we need a way to teach mypy to narrow the return type of a method, rather than narrow the type of a variable. Perhaps I can apply some sort of TypeGuard to the function itself but ... I don't see a clean approach.

I can understand why mypy can't make implications like this. For example, if my implementation body for `does_intersect` were instead `return random.choice([True, False])`, then the value of what I'm intending as a guard on line 18 will be different from the value `intersect` sees on line 8.

What kind of type inference is mypy capable of and is there a reasonable approach to teach Mypy to handle this kind of example? Patience appreciated, I'm totally new to Mypy although I have read through the documentation and didn't find an answer to this kind of question.

Comment: A `x = thing.intersect(other_thing); assert x; return x` does the job.

Comment: @hussic Thanks for responding. However, that's not the sort of job I'm looking to get done.

Comment: do you ever use `does_intersect` on its own without using `intersect`? I ask because this is probably a lot easier if you merge the two methods

Comment: @joel The example is a toy example, not real and not related to anything I'm working on. I'm trying to understand Mypy and asking if there are techniques that would enable Mypy to correctly narrow the inferred type of an object returned from a function when that function is called within a guarded block of code. I.e. contextual type inference.

Comment: Here's an example of the kind of techniques I'm asking about, but in TypeScript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46313086/1354641