# narrowing type in type declaration

Tags: typescript

for the following example, I'm trying to discriminate the base type during a type declaration

```
type Schedule = {
  flag_active : boolean,
}
type Channel = {
  flag_archived : boolean
}

type CreateChangeLog = {
  from : null,
  to : Schedule | Channel
}
type DeleteChangeLog = {
  from : Schedule | Channel,
  to : null
}

type AllChanges = CreateChangeLog | DeleteChangeLog
```

given the `type AllChanges` whose definition I can't alter, how could I retrieve the `Schedule` type?

Comment: you can definitely narrow it down by using `if (change.from && "flag_active" in change.from)` in a for loop

Comment: I'm not following the question, exactly.  Do you want [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NnlXVW) maybe?  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz It can't be a const, as I do not know the exact structure of the array at runtime (data retrieved from API). I want to be able to retrieve `Schedule` type from `AllChanges` type, without needing to run through actual code. It should be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46312206/narrowing-a-return-type-from-a-generic-discriminated-union-in-typescript but I can't seem to get it to work with a "has this key"

Comment: I guess I'm really not understanding your question.  What is the point of `allChanges` in the example?  Could [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/W4jyvN) be what you're looking for?  If so I could maybe write up an answer (although you should probably [edit] the question to remove all references to `allChanges`).  If not, uh, could you clarify?

Comment: @jcalz yeah, `Extract` was what I was looking for

Comment: Okay so I'll write up an answer; could you [edit] the question to remove `allChanges`?

Comment: @jcalz I think the `allChanges` is relevant as I'm trying to do `Extract<typeof allChanges, { flag_active: any }>`. The extraction is being done in another file which is importing the variable

Comment: Given that multiple people addressed the question by trying to change how you defined `allChanges`, I think it's more of a drawback than a benefit to it being in the question. If you phrased the question like "given the type `AllChanges` whose definition I can't alter, how could I retrieve the `Schedule` type", it might be more clear. But I won't belabor the point anymore.

Comment: @jcalz I have changed it. Feel free to suggest an edit if it would be clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) like `ScheduleOrChannel` as computed here:

```
type AllChanges = CreateChangeLog | DeleteChangeLog

type ScheduleOrChannel = NonNullable<AllChanges["from"]>;
// type ScheduleOrChannel = Schedule | Channel
```

and you want to filter it to include only those union members that match a certain supertype, you can use [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) as shown here:

```
type JustSchedule = Extract<ScheduleOrChannel, { flag_active: any }>
// type JustSchedule = Schedule

type JustChannel = Extract<ScheduleOrChannel, { flag_archived: any }>
// type JustChannel = Channel
```

`Extract<T, U>` is just a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) which is [implemented as](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/7612a3afc776d3896a7cdfe4e8d982d3e8ddaa11/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1609)

```
type Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never
```

so you could always write your own custom union-filtering operation that uses other criteria for keeping/rejecting members, such as a `HasKey` utility type:

```
type HasKey<T, K extends PropertyKey> =
    T extends unknown ? K extends keyof T ? T : never : never;

type JustSchedule1 = HasKey<ScheduleOrChannel, "flag_active">
// type JustSchedule1 = Schedule

type JustChannel2 = HasKey<ScheduleOrChannel, "flag_archived">
// type JustChannel2 = Channel
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoIBYQCYFcA2KA3gFDLnIz5wDmA+omMAG4QBcyARgPbeFwgANCQC+JUJFiIUAYQwCQEfMlIVK1enCiYWODjz4QBokuPDR4SZDKhHIcgTQgAZbjRVkKMKNwC2HEAJ8YTUwbg50LDxCZAAfa3kQRXwTCQtpZAARJQh7RKdXd1UvH380TBwCFHiHJKUQijCAoJMSMABPAAcUAEF8fFqnAGdkAF5rWzg8xxc3OKyc6ZACt1MO7vKoqoB5KFrkseQAOW4QI6C4TkIAHj6B-IghgG0AIm8-F4BdAD4AbhIAPQA5DrFCRSqEXb7JSHcHRaoJBRKNZdFAAKVwQzAcKqhwAogAPMBQRjXHGQvaJZKCFTqWgMBBMVgcATtZAib6A4Gg5AYrHklDjAUojZ8sDQ5TjQnE0kCqFU+q0qj0rQ6VjYFkgNkcrkg1G8zHihWSxF1FJtfV0aUkxnXAAqNIAqt9DnbkBAiRAQNgRo7kAB+ZBugIQVhQEUoAAScCGAGkIO17TTY+7Pd6RgAFHzdKAdePtF2jTzkN0eyDp5C4EAAaxA3AA7iAA8gU2WvT7kNWE9wYEHm8HkIow8gQ2H-hbRYaBQBGQ7RuMJskVeHypHBZBvDQMpkQF6coF6yf85dVWdCk+ECMGrESgBMc5j+aXWwpEppm5V2gwumwe91PLFO9DglIA)